# Как выводить элемент только у одного чекбокса?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Нужно, чтобы при нажатии на чекбокс все остальные кнопки убирались, а кнопка "применить" должна быть только у того чекбокса, который нажат последним. Т.е. кнопка должна быть одна.

Чекбоксы должны оставаться выделены.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.check-list :checkbox').on('change', function() {
    var filterId = $(this).find('input:checked').context.id;
  $('.' + filterId + '').show(300);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="check-list ">
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="idchkk_2_1_0" value="13794">
    <label for="idchkk_2_1_0">
      <i></i>
      BARS SILVER
    </label>
    <span style="display: none;" class="idchkk_2_1_0"><button type="submit" class="ctf-b-btn-aply">Применить</button></span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="idchkk_2_1_1" value="13647">
    <label for="idchkk_2_1_1">
      <i></i>
      BLAK HORSE
    </label>
    <span style="display: none;" class="idchkk_2_1_1"><button type="submit" class="ctf-b-btn-aply">Применить</button></span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="idchkk_2_1_2" value="13659">
    <label for="idchkk_2_1_2">
      <i></i>
      BOSCH
    </label>
    <span style="display: none;" class="idchkk_2_1_2"><button type="submit" class="ctf-b-btn-aply">Применить</button></span>
  </li>  
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Зачем 3 кнопки?

Можно сделать и одну и двигать её по мере надобности.
Вот мой код:
https://jsfiddle.net/j1wxwjfb/

html код:

```
<button type="submit" id="button" style="display: none; position: absolute;">Применить</button>
<ul class="check-list">
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="idchkk_2_1_0" value="13794">
    <label for="idchkk_2_1_0">BARS SILVER</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="idchkk_2_1_1" value="13647">
    <label for="idchkk_2_1_1">BLAK HORSE</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="idchkk_2_1_2" value="13659">
    <label for="idchkk_2_1_2">BOSCH</label>
  </li>  
</ul>
```

JQuery код:

```
$('.check-list :checkbox').on('change', function(e) {

    // определить последний выбранный элемент
    var lastElement = undefined;
    $(".check-list input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function(index, element){
        lastElement = element;
    });

    if (lastElement == undefined)
        $('#button').hide(300);
    else
    {
        var pos = $(lastElement).next().position();
        var width = $(lastElement).next().width();
        $('#button').hide(300, function(){
            $('#button').css({left: pos.left + width + 15, top: pos.top,}).show(300);
        });
    }
});
```

Ну позицию можно чуть скорректировать чтобы по центру выдавалась

Answer (score 0):

JS тут не требуется: https://jsfiddle.net/hd8d2d0e/1/

```
button {
  transition: opacity 600ms cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);;
  opacity: 0;
}

.check-list input[type=checkbox]:checked + label + button    {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: `кнопка должна быть одна.`

Comment: я, наверное, не очень хорошо описал проблему. проблема в том, что когда нажимаешь на чекбокс, все остальные кнопки "применить" должны убираться. а чекбоксы оставаться выделенными.

Comment: Тогда JS надо, согласен!
https://jsfiddle.net/hd8d2d0e/2/

Comment: Только тогда это должны быть радио-кнопки по хорошему..

Comment: `Чекбоксы должны оставаться выделены.`

Comment: вот так? :)
https://jsfiddle.net/j1wxwjfb/

Comment: @Zhihar думаю что почти так, вместо последнего выбраного кнопка возле последнего в списке )

Answer (score 0):

Вот так вроде работает :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var _history = [];

  $('.check-list :checkbox').on('change', function() {
    var c = $(this).prop('checked');
    var filterId = $(this).find('input:checked').context.id;

    if (!c) {
      delHistory(filterId);
      if ($('.' + filterId + '').css('display') != 'none') {
        $('.' + _history[0] + '').show(300);
      }
      $('.' + filterId + '').css('display', 'none');
    } else {
      _history.unshift(filterId);
      $('.check-list span').css('display', 'none');
      $('.' + filterId + '').show(300);
    }
  });

  function delHistory(elem) {
    var index = _history.indexOf(elem);
    if (index > -1) {
      _history.splice(index, 1);
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="check-list ">
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="idchkk_2_1_0" value="13794">
    <label for="idchkk_2_1_0">
      <i></i>
      BARS SILVER
    </label>
    <span style="display: none;" class="idchkk_2_1_0"><button type="submit" class="ctf-b-btn-aply">Применить</button></span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="idchkk_2_1_1" value="13647">
    <label for="idchkk_2_1_1">
      <i></i>
      BLAK HORSE
    </label>
    <span style="display: none;" class="idchkk_2_1_1"><button type="submit" class="ctf-b-btn-aply">Применить</button></span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="idchkk_2_1_2" value="13659">
    <label for="idchkk_2_1_2">
      <i></i>
      BOSCH
    </label>
    <span style="display: none;" class="idchkk_2_1_2"><button type="submit" class="ctf-b-btn-aply">Применить</button></span>
  </li>
</ul>
```